# C# AES algorithm - Where and how should i store the Key and IV

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, key, aes

I am using AES algorithm for encryption and decryption of password **when** the [PasswordFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershippasswordformat.aspx) is Encrypted for the asp.net membership system. If the format was Hashed i would generate unique salted value for each password and store it in a column in the table where password is stored. But for encryption it is different i am worrying about below

#### 1

If i generate unique `IV`, `Key` for each password then i have to maintain them somewhere. Is this correct approach from point of security?

#### 2

If i HardCode `IV` and `Key` in application configuration(**web.config**) file then there i will have to worry about what happens when any of the above pair changes? How should i handle this situation?

#### 3

Give me your ideas for what i should do. i will put them here :)

Comment: Why are you encrypting the password rather than hashing it?

Comment: @BenRobinson  Did you notice the **WHEN** bolded. This was especially to answer your doubt, the format is configurable and i cannot be the person who always does that. It is in the hands of client i can least advice them that's all. Anything more i can do for you?

Comment: Presumably if you chose to encrypt it you have a reason, that reason has a bearing on the correct answer, e.g. if you just need passwords to be decryptable but don't need that function as part of the app then the answer would be different to if you need the app to be able to auto decrypt that password as part of it's functionality. WHY is always important, because the answer might also just be don't do it because your reasons for doing it are fallacious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers:

1. No, there is no need for a unique key per password - and it would not be useful as your key would have to be stored somewhere. You might as well store the password in that safe system.
2. You should not store the key in the same system with the same access conditions as the password. This would make encrypted storage futile. You should put the key somewhere else protected against abuse, and perform the encryption within that system.

You are much better off choosing a function such as PBKDF2 and store the result of that. Key management is a tricky thing and should not be choosen without a good idea on how to proceed (hire a professional if you go that way).

Finally, the whole idea of an IV is that it protects plain text when *the same* key is used. You may set the IV to all zero's if you have a key per plain text / cipher text pair. It is however the idea that you use a single key, stored somewhere save, and a random IV stored with the cipher text.

As said, if you did not know this already, then your scheme is unsafe, because there are many other things to consider, and you probably didn't.

PS Microsoft has some ways to securily store keys in the system, you might want to search stackoverflow for that. I'm however not an expert regarding the MS API's.